# Url parameter to model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a view that takes a parameter and returns a csv file based on a queryset:

```
def rfidi_list(request, id=None):
    if id == None:
        raise Http404

    rfid_list = Rfid.objects.filter(----).values_list('rfid_st', flat=True)
    import csv

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="rfidi_list.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(rfid_list)

    return response
```

I have a model called *Rfid* that has boolean fields named: *vrata1*, *vrata2*, *vrata3*

I want to filter queryset based on the id that came in url. If the id was 1, I would return objects with vrata1 = True, if it was 2 I'd like to get qs with objects with vrata2 = True.

Thank you

Comment: So do you have a question or do you simply expect us to do your work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the lookup filter this way:

```
rfid_list = Rfid.objects.filter(
    **{
        '{}{}'.format('vrata', id): True
      }
).values_list('rfid_st',flat=True)
```

concat 'vrata' and the ID, and then convert the syntax to the django ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In case anyone wonders, I passed the id as a string and added the **kwargs to filter. So it looked like this

```
string = 'vrata' + id

rfid_list = Rfid.objects.filter(**{ string : True}).values_list('rfid_st',flat=True)
```